# Android: Indeterminate Circular Progress with rate correlated to work

Tags: android, progress-bar

There are many discussions of Indeterminate Circular Progress spinner.  But I want one that actually correlates with work progress.  In this case, I have multiple ongoing (i.e. never ending) data feeds and I want to show that the feeds are working.  I have a table layout with each of the data feeds and at the end of each row, I want an indeterminate spinner that shows the rate of data being received.  When a data stream is at full rate, the spinner should be at maximum spin rate, but if the stream slows down the spinner should also slow; and if it stops, in the spinner should stop.   I've read the Android documentation and once Indeterminate is set to true, the incrementProgressBy() method is ignored ("In indeterminate mode, the progress bar shows a cyclic animation without an indication of progress. " [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)).  I would like to rate of spinning to correlated to the actual data rate being recieved.

Comment: that's not what the stock progress bar does, sorry.

Comment: Any ideas for other methods?